# Is there a way how to connect botframework via Oauth?

Tags: oauth, botframework

It is possible to authorize some MS apps using OAuth and login form. If the user logins and allows the permissions the app wants then as a developer you can read (and write) some data via API.

Is it possible with https://botframework.com? I don't want my clients to have to write down the `client_id` and `client_secret` in my administration. I just want them to give me permission via logging in and let me download this data.

I've read [MS docs about OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code) and have seen that the possible scopes doesn't include the bot platform.

To demonstrate what I mean here is a [demo application](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&state=12345) from the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to check [AuthBot](https://github.com/microsoftdx/authbot).

> AuthBot is a .Net library for Azure Active Directory authentication on
>   bots built via Microsoft Bot Framework.

In short, when using AuthBot, your users will receive a link that they will open and perform the OAuth flow. The users won't have to write the credentials in the bot (which could be a security concern) and instead will be done in the MS login page. Then a callback (already provided by the library) will be called and the conversation with the user will be resumed.

You can also check [AzureBot](https://github.com/Microsoft/azurebot) as an example of a Bot that uses AuthBot and that retrieve information only available if you are logged.

Comment: Thanks for Help Ezequiel! Do I understand well that the OAuth flow is available for Azure only?

Comment: I hope it's possible to build such a link even without .Net, e.g. https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=32746e6f-a7ec-42ce-9101-f0d3125b662f&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default

Comment: No! OAuth OAuth is an open standard for authorization, commonly used. It's not something Azure specific. You can build the URL manually, but you still need to perform some call to get the auth code to then get the token. The AuthBot library shows how to do that in the context of a bot. Are u running a Node.js bot?

Comment: Ohh got it. You somehow want to authenticate against dev.botframework.com and access the bot details of that account so you can get the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppSecret of the bot, correct? I'm not aware if that's possible. I don't think so as there is no API to provision/retrieve information about bots.

Comment: Man, I have to learn how to explain things to people. :D I think it's possible at the moment too but still, I hope that I am wrong and just comes here and pastes in the correct link. Thx Ezeq!