# Microsoft chat bot authentication

Tags: asp.net, oauth, botframework

Is it possible to authenticate a chat bot developed with Microsoft Bot framework, so that only authorized user can able to access the chatbot?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is either too broad or will get a yes/no answer, which is probably not what you want. For guidance on asking questions here please read https:/stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way how to connect botframework via Oauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534461/is-there-a-way-how-to-connect-botframework-via-oauth)

Answer (score 0):

You must use [AuthBot](https://github.com/microsoftdx/authbot)

AuthBot is a .Net library for Azure Active Directory authentication on bots built via Microsoft Bot Framework.

Some feature are:

- Support endpoints V1, V2 and B2C (currently only working with v1 and
  v2, we're still working on the B2C scenario)
- Allow easy and secure sign in, even in chat sessions including multiple users
- Allow to securely sign out, including clearing browser cookies
- Enable scenarios where bots need to communicate with other services such as Office 365 or Azure by obtaining access tokens

This AuthBot library is also available as a Nuget package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AuthBot

The BotAuth repo contains samples for all of the providers plus a multi-provider sample. Additionally, there are two Azure AD v2 samples for building Microsoft Graph enabled bots that can be cloned into your own project. One is a very basic bot and the other is a bot leveraging LUIS.

[Azure AD v1 Sample](https://github.com/richdizz/BotAuth/tree/master/CSharp/SampleAADv1Bot)

[Azure AD v2 Sample](https://github.com/richdizz/BotAuth/tree/master/CSharp/SampleAADv2Bot)

[Azure AD B2C Sample](https://github.com/richdizz/BotAuth/tree/master/CSharp/SampleAADb2cBot)

[Generic OAuth2 Sample](https://github.com/richdizz/BotAuth/tree/master/CSharp/SampleGenericOAuth2Bot)

[Multi-provider Sample](https://github.com/richdizz/BotAuth/tree/master/CSharp/SampleMultiProviderBot)

[Basic Microsoft Graph Sample](https://github.com/richdizz/microsoft-graph-bot-quickstart)

[Microsoft Graph Sample with LUIS](https://github.com/richdizz/microsoft-graph-bot-quickstart-luis)

Answer (score 0):

There are actually A few options here:

- As Wilson Vargas mentioned [AuthBot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/authbot) is one
- Another one in [BotAuth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth)(for node writen in typescript)
- You can also do your own custom Auth with OAuth as you would in an MVC Web Site. The once the user has logged in redirect to a page containing the webchat control or your own implementation of directline. I personally followed [this blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) to get started on this.  The nice thing about this method is that the user does not interact with the bot to log in.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason for your suggestion.Is it possible to implement custom authentication using database in Microsoft chat bot ?

Comment: Yes, it would be.  I do not have an example implementation to share with you though.  So you would have to do some figuring it out on your own.  Good luck.